# WPDB Join with custom table

Tags: wpdb

I am trying to query info from a custom table created by a calendar feed.  The calendar feed created a post with the title for each event, but the event data is in a different table instead of post_meta.  Here is what I am trying with no results:

```
$sql = "SELECT post_id".
"FROM {$wpdb->prefix}calp_events".
"JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts ON (ID = post_id)";

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

The id of each calp_events is the same as the post ID.  I want to be able to echo results from both tables after my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to distinguish which table your ID and post_id  come from. Take a look below and notice how the tables get a variable assigned. You could also just use the table name, but this reads easier.

```
SELECT P.post_id FROM [prefix]_calp_events as EV
JOIN [prefix]_posts as P ON EV.ID = P.post_id
```

You stated that you want to read the results from both tables. The join actually returns only matching records in both tables. Check out https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp for details on how joins work.

Comment: Your answer is correct when it comes to the join function.  I ended up having to go another direction to get the results I need.  Thanks!